# How to save png images with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am trying to use OpenCV to convert the results of the model I trained into a png image. My output has 4 channels, and I am not sure how to convert these 4 channels to png.

```
# Load the model
model = CNNSEG()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()

for iteration, sample in enumerate(test_data_loader):
    img = sample
    print(img.shape)

    plt.imshow(img[0,...].squeeze(), cmap='gray') #visualise all images in test set
    plt.pause(1)
    
    # output the results
    img_in = img.unsqueeze(1)
    output = model(img_in) # shape: [2, 4, 96, 96]
```

As here shows, the shape of output is [2, 4, 96, 96] which are batch size, channels, height and width. So how could I do to convert it to png image?

Comment: just do `imwrite`, what's the issue? Did you look into this at all?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh, look at the shape, again. not appropriate for imwrite()

Comment: @berak you can loop through the array and write it one by one. Again, what's the issue? Or do you mean that the rgba are the first dimension?

Answer (score 2):

To write the images you need to convert the output into the right format (assuming outputs are in the 0,1 range):

```
# Convert outputs from 0-1 to 0, 255
img_in *= 255.0

# Convert floats to bytes
img_in = img_in.astype(np.uint8)

# Transpose the images from channel first (4, 96, 96) to channel last (96, 96, 4)
image1 = img_in[0, :, :, :].transpose(2, 1, 0)
image2 = img_in[1, :, :, :].transpose(2, 1, 0)
```

Then it's just a matter of saving the images:

```
cv2.imwrite('./example_path/image1.png', image1)
cv2.imwrite('./example_path/image2.png', image2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to split your image into two essentially and then save them individually.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = np.ones((2,4,96,96),dtype=np.uint8) #creating a random image


img1 = img[0,:,:,:] #extracting the two separate images
img2 = img[1,:,:,:]

img1_reshaped = img1.transpose() #reshaping them to the desired form of (w,h,c)
img2_reshaped = img2.transpose()

cv2.imwrite("img1.png",img1_reshaped) #save the images as .png
cv2.imwrite("img2.png",img2_reshaped)
```

Comment: reshape wont work. you did not try this

Comment: @berak I did save the image after reshaping.

Comment: @berak agree with you. reshape won't work. Checked this example --> https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.5.0/tutorials/basic/reshape_transpose.html

Thanks for pointing it out. Updating the answer